# hide string <property name="password" value="***"/> when public on GitHub?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

How I can hide string  from my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, when I public code on GitHub?

I can't exclude this file - it contain many important settings!

Comment: are you using maven for the build?

Comment: You can try something that Travis does: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion your best bet is to use O/S environment variables for such things. That's what Heroku does, and they are a-ok.

Reasons:

- cross-platform
- easily read by many programming languages
- only user or root can read
- survives reboot
- never check passwords into source control by accident
- easy to have different config on different machines without editing any files

If you use a `<context:property-placeholder />` in your spring app context config then Spring can read O/S env vars like `$USERNAME`

You might have to restart your IDE after changing env vars though.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not possible. You have to use other mechanisms, e.g. don't store the password at all, but use system properties and configure them, when you execute the application.